# Is it possible to install CentOS with ReiserFS in VPS?

Tags: centos, vps, filesystems, reiserfs

I'm confused because as I know, CentOS doesn't support ReiserFS.

But my previous CentOS VPS is running on ReiserFS.

```
Filesystem    Type   1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/vzfs reiserfs   314572800  10694756 303878044   4% /
none         tmpfs      262144         4    262140   1% /dev
```

In system admin view, What make it possible to install CentOS with ReiserFS in VPS?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it's probably a case of your VPS swapped in a new kernel compiled with ReiserFS support, instead of using the kernel that came with CentOS which is not built with ReiserFS support.